# how can I change child node css?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to enable view / hide feature in my faq questions, but however at the moment to trying to access to my child `answers_body` with `children` I got an error . `children is not a function`, how can I properly access to `answers_body` in order to change `display:none` to `display:block`

```
<section class="faqs">
  <div class="accordion row">
      <div class="__block col-lg-7 mx-auto py-3">
          <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-start">
              <div class="col-11">
                  <h3 class="__question">
                      demo
                  </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="12"><path fill="none" stroke="#5267DF" stroke-width="3" d="M1 1l8 8 8-8" /></svg>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="answers_body"> I want to access to this node in order to display it 
              <div class="col">
                  <p class="answer">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt justo eget ultricies fringilla. Phasellus blandit ipsum quis quam ornare mattis.
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</section>

$('.__question').click(function(){
  var $parent = $(this);
  console.log($patern[0].InnerText)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a toggle effect for your faq, then you can try the following.

```
$('.__question').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents('.accordion.row');
  if (parent.find('.answers_body').hasClass('answers-active')) {
    parent.find('.answers_body').removeClass('answers-active');
  } else {
    parent.find('.answers_body').addClass('answers-active');
  }
});
```

Here you need to find the parent that is common to both the element you are clicking and the element you need show. Then using `.find()` method you can target the element and show. Refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/a2qfwc8p/9/)

**UPDATE**

Since you said this is not working, I think the parent class that is used for all faq is wrong. If you can update the code, I can help with that. Else you can use the following code.

```
$('.__question').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('.row').siblings('.answers_body');
  if (parent.hasClass('answers-active')) {
    parent.removeClass('answers-active');
  } else {
    parent.addClass('answers-active');
  }
});
```

Comment: how can I avoid getting open all parents since I only want to open the selected one?

Comment: Does this open all parents ? So which is the parent class for all faqs ?

Comment: this `accordion`

Comment: That should work. Can you update the code with more faq ? Atleast 2 faqs ?

Comment: There would be a div with a class that is repeated for all faqs. That class should be called as parent. Since I don't know the class you can try the updated part of my answer.